# Google Apps Script for 2 Dynamic Dropdowns from 2 separate tables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following Google Apps onEdit Script which looks up the table in columns A:D in my 'DropDown Lists' sheet. This works for the dropdown in column C of the 'HISOP Training' sheet when the Branch is selected in the dropdown in column A of the same sheet:

```js
//Dynamic Dropdown for HISOP Training
{
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var tablists = 'Dropdown Lists';
    var tabValidation = 'HISOP Training';
    var ss = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    var datass = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(tablists);
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if (
      activeCell.getColumn() == 1 &&
      activeCell.getRow() > 1 &&
      ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation
    ) {
      activeCell
        .offset(0, 2)
        .clearContent()
        .clearDataValidations();
      var base = datass.getRange(2, 1, 1, 5).getValues();
      var baseIndex = base[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
      Logger.log(baseIndex);
      if (baseIndex != 0) {
        //Dynamic dropdown for 'Employee'
        var validationRange = datass.getRange(6, baseIndex, 150);
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(validationRule);
         }
    }
    if (ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation) {
      var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
      if (lock.tryLock(0)) {
        autoid_(ss);
        lock.releaseLock();
      }
    }
    
  }
```

I now also want the dropdown in column D of the 'HISOP Training' sheet to select from the range BO:BR of the 'Dropdown List' sheet when the Branch in Column A of the 'HISOP Training' sheet is selected but I don't know how to write the script for this.

This is an image of my 'HISOP Training' sheet:

[image]

This is a link to a sanitised version of my spreadsheet:

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ih83ZNo9E4fMP0oyKwUFM6ZgG_zQRFLGcHlPO14i3qc/edit?usp=sharing)

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Final answer:

```js
function myOnEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HISOP Training');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dropdown Lists');
  var value = e.value;
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  
  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='New York' && row>2 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='HISOP Training'){
    // 2 is for dropdown D
    var dropdownData = sheet2.getRange("A6:A150").getValues().flat();
    var dropdownData2 = sheet2.getRange("BO4:BO150").getValues().flat();
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+2).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var allowDropdown2 = sheet.getRange(row, col+3).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData2, true).build();
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
    allowDropdown2.setDataValidation(rule2);
  }

  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='London' && row>2 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='HISOP Training'){
    var dropdownData = sheet2.getRange("B6:B150").getValues().flat();
    var dropdownData2 = sheet2.getRange("BP4:BP150").getValues().flat();
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+2).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var allowDropdown2 = sheet.getRange(row, col+3).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData2, true).build();
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
    allowDropdown2.setDataValidation(rule2);
  }
  
  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='Paris' && row>2 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='HISOP Training'){
    var dropdownData = sheet2.getRange("C6:C150").getValues().flat();
    var dropdownData2 = sheet2.getRange("BQ4:BQ150").getValues().flat();
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+2).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var allowDropdown2 = sheet.getRange(row, col+3).clearDataValidations().clearContent();    
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData2, true).build();
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
    allowDropdown2.setDataValidation(rule2);
  }
  
  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='Tokyo' && row>2 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='HISOP Training'){
    var dropdownData = sheet2.getRange("D6:D150").getValues().flat();
    var dropdownData2 = sheet2.getRange("BR4:BR150").getValues().flat();
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+2).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var allowDropdown2 = sheet.getRange(row, col+3).clearDataValidations().clearContent();    
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData2, true).build();
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
    allowDropdown2.setDataValidation(rule2);
  }
  }
```

Comment: So, for clarification, you basically want to be able to select a dropdown in column D **only** if Column A is selected  but not in any other occasion am I right?

Comment: Yes - that is correct. I want the dropdown in column A (the Branch) to determine the result in the column C and D dropdowns. Column C to source the data  from columns A:D of the Dropdown Lists sheet and column D to source the data from columns BO:BR of the Dropdown Lists sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my interpretation of your question you want to be able to only select a dropdrown of values in columns C and D only if a specific value is selected in column A. To provide a solution to this question instead of providing a specific answer to your sheet case I have provided a general solution abstracting the question so that others with similar questions can easily interpolate the answer and use it as well. You will just need to adapt this answer to you case.

To achieve this I have set up a conditional on an `onEdit` function to catch changes in the sheet and if this conditional is met (in your case if the branch in column A is selected) then you will be able to select from C and D dropdowns. The following code that solves the issue has self explanatory comments:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // Get the value of the cell changed
  var value = e.value;
  
  // Get col and row of the cell changed to make sure it was in col A
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  
  // If col A. Here you could also add another condition to the if for instance if the value on col A
  // is equal to whatever value you want to select in the dropdown in A, then execute this
  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='VALUE 1'){
  // Get the data for the range of the dropdown. Here you choose if you want to insert dropdowns for C and D
    var dropdownData = sheet.getRange("C1:C5").getValues().flat();
    
    // Get the cell we will let the dropdown go (clear all previous content and data validations)
    // In your case these you be the columns D and 
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+1).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    
    // Create rules for the respective dropdowns of C and D (in this case is just one rule because I am 
    // just using a single dropdown to exemplify how to do this
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    
    // Set the data validation
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
  
  // SECOND RANGE. REPEAT FOR THE REST IF WE HAVE MORE SUB RANGES
  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='VALUE 2'){
    var dropdownData = sheet.getRange("D1:D5").getValues().flat();
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+1).clearDataValidations().clearContent();

    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

And this is how this example would look like in the sheet:

[image]

As you seem to have difficulties understanding, I have adjusted the general case scenario to your specific situation and I have done for you both the right dropdowns for columns **C** and **D**. These are as follow:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HISOP Training');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dropdown Lists');
  var value = e.value;
  
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  
  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='New York' && row>2 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='HISOP Training'){
    // 2 is for dropdown C
    var dropdownData = sheet2.getRange("BO4:BO49").getValues().flat();
    var dropdownData2 = sheet2.getRange("Z2:Z4").getValues().flat();
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+3).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var allowDropdown2 = sheet.getRange(row, col+2).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData2, true).build();
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
    allowDropdown2.setDataValidation(rule);
  }

  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='London' && row>2 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='HISOP Training'){
    var dropdownData = sheet.getRange("BP4:BP45").getValues().flat();
    var dropdownData2 = sheet2.getRange("AA2:AA3").getValues().flat();
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+1).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var allowDropdown2 = sheet.getRange(row, col+2).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData2, true).build();
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
    allowDropdown2.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
  
  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='Paris' && row>2 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='HISOP Training'){
    var dropdownData = sheet.getRange("BQ4:BQ43").getValues().flat();
    var dropdownData2 = sheet2.getRange("AB2:AB4").getValues().flat();
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+1).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var allowDropdown2 = sheet.getRange(row, col+2).clearDataValidations().clearContent();    
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData2, true).build();
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
    allowDropdown2.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
  
  if(col==1 && e.range.getValue()=='Tokyo' && row>2 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='HISOP Training'){
    var dropdownData = sheet.getRange("BR4:BR33").getValues().flat();
    var dropdownData2 = sheet2.getRange("AC2:AC3").getValues().flat();
    var allowDropdown = sheet.getRange(row, col+1).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
    var allowDropdown2 = sheet.getRange(row, col+2).clearDataValidations().clearContent();    
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData, true).build();
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownData2, true).build();
    allowDropdown.setDataValidation(rule);
    allowDropdown2.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry Mateo but I can't get this to work. I have created a Data Validation set in column D of my HISOP Training sheet to look up the range in the Dropdown Lists sheet BO4:BR. I set the script to var dropdownData = sheet.getRange("'Dropdown Lists'!BO4:BO").getValues().flat(); but the dropdown returns the whole range BO4:BR

Comment: That's because you are trying to get the range from another sheet with a different sheet object. Unline with formulas, in Apps Script you cannot put ```Dropdown Lists!'A1'```. Instead, you must first get the sheet object and then get the range in that sheet. So what you rather want is ```var dropdownData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dropdown Lists').getRange('BO4:BO').getValues().flat();``` Let me know if that worked. Also, which values do you want, from BO1 to BO4?

Comment: Thank you - the dropdown in column D of the HISOP Register will use the data validation range from the Dropdown Lists sheet BO4:BO150, BP4:BP150, BQ4:BQ150 or BR4:BR150 depending on the selected branch in column A of the HISOP Register. The dropdown in column C of the HISOP Register will use the data validation range from the Dropdown Lists sheet A4:A150, B4:B150, C4:C150 or D4:D150 depending on the selected branch in column A of the HISOP Register. There are 15 branches

Comment: I get the following error in the Executions: ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at [unknown function](Code:238:15) which is this line of code: var value = e.value;

Comment: Yes, that error is normal because you are running an ```onEdit``` function and as it hasn't have received any event yet when you running it will not be able to get that property from an empty object. However, don't worry about it **beacuse the function will already be running in your sheet, so test it to see if it is doing what it's supposed to do from the script**. Hope that helps :D

Comment: Using your code, I have modified for just one branch and for the dropdown in column D. Please see the code added to my question above. Nothing happens in the column D dropdown when I select 'EBOP' in the column A dropdown.

Comment: Hi ! I have modified my answer accodingly to show you how to add more subranges. You would basically would have to repeat the ```IF``` conditionals for each of the subranges and make the conditions to match all the ```A``` dropdown list values. Let me know if you did not understand something :D

Comment: I have updated as you have suggested. This is for the column D dropdown only (the list of items for each branch depending on the branch selected in column A). This code clears the dropdown validation in column D but it doesn't reload the dropdown. I get the error: Exception: The data validation rule has more items than the limit of 500. Use the ‘List from a range’ criteria instead.

Also, how do I write the code for the column C dropdown (the list of employees depending on the branch selected in column A)?

Comment: Hi ! As you were having trouble understanding, I have edited my answer to also provide a specific solution for your situation, more precisely I have written the code that you must integrate to apply the dropdowns to **C** and **D**. Let me know if you still have any issues with that. Also, remember that accepting and upvoting answer, helps the community to find easier what worked and reward users that provided solutions. :D

Comment: I changed a couple of sheet numbers, column offsets and Rule numbers. It works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time and effort. I have posted the modified final answer into my original question. You may want to change your so that it can be referenced by others.